# Property set/get example for operator needed

Tags: python, add-on, properties, operator

Still trying to wrap a property into my Addon where I can dynamically control the values of the resulting variable.  Take the default operator_mesh_add example and alter the  definition of the **width** FloatProperty to be:

```
def get_func(self):
    print('get_')
    return self.actual_width

def set_func(self, value):
    print('set_')
    self.actual_width = value

class AddBox(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Add a simple box mesh"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.primitive_box_add"
    bl_label = "Add Box"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    actual_width: 1.0

    width: FloatProperty(
        name="Width",
        description="Box Width",
        min=0.01, max=100.0,
        default=1.0,
        set=set_func,
        get=get_func,
    )
```

this gives:

```
 AttributeError: 'MESH_OT_primitive_box_add' object has no attribute 'actual_width'
```

if the get/set functions access the self.width member, there is an infinite recursion.  We really need a tangible example of how to use get/set within an operator setting.

Following [How to use set/get property callbacks correctly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49264/how-to-use-set-get-property-callbacks-correctly) and making set/get:

```
def get_func(self):
    print('get_')
    return self['width']

def set_func(self, value):
    print('set_')
    self['width'] = value
```

results in:

```
KeyError: 'bpy_struct[key]: key "width" not found'
```

What is the right way?

Comment: `self.actual_width` doesn't work because you don't have an instance attribute, you've declared a class attribute. Therefore you would need to use either `AddBox.actual_width` or `type(self).actual_width`.

Comment: The proper way for most use cases would be through the key based access. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126458/internal-get-set-function-of-property The important difference is the use of `.get()` for when the key doesn't yet exist.